# Image of a finite umramified morphism

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $f\colon X\to Y$ be a finite surjective unramified morphism between projective varieties (irreducible and reduced) over $\mathbb{C}$. Moreover, we assume that $X$ is smooth.

Question: Is $Y$ smooth as well?

When $f$ is flat, then $f$ is 'etale and the answer is yes. Does this remain true without the flatness assumption?

Comment: If $Y$ is normal, then yes, because then $f$ is in fact etale (see Lemma 2.2 or Lemma 2.3 in https://arxiv.org/abs/2011.12840)

Comment: @AriyanJavanpeykar This helps a lot! Do you think $Y$ is automatically normal in this situation?

Comment: KReiser's example shows that $Y$ might not be normal even with $X$ smooth. Note that normality can be replaced by unibranch (slightly weaker). KReiser's example is the standard example of a non-unibranch variety.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Consider the normalization of the nodal cubic $\Bbb P^1\to C$: this satisfies all your conditions but the target is not smooth.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But is there any higher-dimensional example?

Comment: Sure, take a product of this example with any normal scheme.